# Training a model using a pre-trained model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have a pre-trained model in Keras. I would like to train another model where the output of the model is input for the already trained model and the output of the already trained model is being used in the loss function of the untrained model. Something like

```
in_a + mod_b(some kind of feedback from B here) --> Model A --> out_a --> Model B --> out_b

error  = (in_a - out_b)**2
```

and then use this error to train Model A.
`in_a` can be treated as a constant in this system and there is a feedback loop as well

Any ideas how to do this in keras or tensorflow

Comment: Do you want `Model B`, the pretrained model, to be trained as well, along with `Model A`? In any case, the gradient from `Model B`'s loss must flow through `Model B` and into `Model A`. So you simply leave the setup to `Model B` unchanged, and set its input as the output of `Model A`.

Comment: No I dont want to train model B at all

Comment: If you want to use tensorflow see here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea. Build Model A until the output layer, which we'll assume is compatible with Model B's input layer. Also, let's assume you're Using a pretrained VGG16 as Model B. You'll load the model with pretrained weights:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

# Model A is trainable
x = Input(shape=(32,))
x_d = Dense(10)(x)
model_a_out = Dense(10)(x_d)

# Model B
model_b = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
# Freeze Model B
for layer in model_b.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# Set input to Model B as output from A
model_b.input = model_a_out

# Train as usual
model_b.compile... and model_b.fit ...
```

Another way of doing it is first you want to build A. and then:

```
for layer in model_b.layers:
  new_layer = layer
  new_layer.trainable = False
  model_a.add(new_layer)
```

Check out the Keras [Applications](https://keras.io/applications/) page for some ideas.

Comment: In case of method 1, the loss function of model A depends on the output of model B how do I specify that as none of the pre-built ones will do. If I specify my own loss function for calculating error in the question then what value would get passed to it. I want to pass the value of out_b but model A will pass out_a to the loss function

Comment: In method 2 if I add model B to model A and set trainable to false then I can't do the feedback thing out_a + (some additions) and then input to model_B. Some kind of custom layer all this (out_a + some additions is doing is adding some extra point from some kind of stack) might work

Comment: I think it can be done using the functional api in keras